# R subsetting with multiple conditions

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I'm trying to optimally change values in matrix alpha based on a criterium on matrix beta:

```
alpha <- matrix(0,9)
beta <- matrix(1:3,3)
alpha[beta>1] <- beta[beta>1]
```

This gives `beta` of `1 2 3` and `alpha` of `0 2 3 0 2 3 0 2 3`.

While I'm not sure the above is the most efficient way of doing it, in fact I also want to change values in the first part of the alpha matrix only, i.e. the first three entries (above, because beta is a third of the size of alpha, entries mod 3 in alpha are the same). I have tried the following:

```
alpha <- matrix(0,9)
beta <- matrix(1:3,3)
alpha[1:3 & beta>1] <- beta[beta>1]
```

This still return `alpha` of `0 2 3 0 2 3 0 2 3`, rhather than `0 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0` which is what I would like to get. How do I make it work?

Comment: You want to apply what to the first half of `alpha`?

Comment: Edited for clarification.

Comment: Given that `beta` is generated using `rnorm()`, I don't think you can guarantee that `beta[beta > 0]` will always result in 50 elements to overwrite over `alpha[1:50, ]`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: If I understand correctly, I don't think this is correct - the code above iterates through the whole 100 entries of `alpha` (does the same thing to `alpha[1]` as to `alpha[51]` etc.)

Comment: Just do `alpha[which(beta > 1)] <- beta[beta > 1]`

Comment: BTW, what really happens (unlike I said at the beginning) is because `beta > 1` is shorter than `alpha` it is being rolled over and over again, thus another option to avoid it, is to limit the search within `alpha` by doing `alpha[1:3][beta>1] <- beta[beta>1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you want to work on the first half of your matrix and replace only the values which suit a certain criterion. In your case `> 0`.

```
set.seed(357)
alpha <- matrix(0,10)
beta <- matrix(rnorm(5),5)
beta

           [,1]
[1,] -1.2411173
[2,] -0.5832050
[3,]  0.3947471
[4,]  1.5042111
[5,]  0.7667997
```

Only the last three rows should be applied (to the rows 3, 4 and 5 of `alpha`).

```
rownames(alpha) <- 1:nrow(alpha)
alpha[rownames(alpha) %in% 1:nrow(beta), ][beta > 0] <- beta[beta > 0]
alpha

        [,1]
1  0.0000000
2  0.0000000
3  0.3947471
4  1.5042111
5  0.7667997
6  0.0000000
7  0.0000000
8  0.0000000
9  0.0000000
10 0.0000000
```

Comment: You could just do `alpha[which(beta > 0)] <- beta[beta > 0]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg your method would work implicitly for first `nrow(beta)` rows. I added the complication with `rownames` to make it a bit more general.

Comment: Maybe you are right, I didn't dig up too deeply into OP intentions.